# what does shortlink link type in HTML used for?

Tags: html, hyperlink

`...link rel="shortlink" href="url-examle"...`

I want to understand what does this element used for, and is this `href="url-examle"` URL is a shortlink for the current html document URL, or what?

And is this `href="url-examle"` URL an arbitrary value I can write from my brain, or is it created with special tools like https://tinyurl.com website?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `rel=shortlink` is primarily used to identify a short link.

E.g:

```
<link rel="shortlink" type="text/html" href="http://flic.kr/p/6XuLyD">
```

Usually used for space constrained and/or manual entry.

Comment: Sharing the source of your information is usually a good idea. I found this link which might be helpful

http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-shortlink#:~:text=Proposed%20usage%3A%20by%20adding%20rel,order%20and%20hightlighting%20is%20lost

Answer (score 0):

See [the specification](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shortlink/wikis/Specification.wiki):

> The shortlink relation allows webmasters to specify a short link to use for the resource, thereby avoiding having to obtain one from a potentially unreliable third party URL shortening service such as tinyurl.com.
>
> Such links are useful for space-constrained applications (e.g. microblogging including Twitter and mobile Internet) as well as any time URLs need to be manually entered (e.g. when they are printed or spoken).

The spec goes on to describe how to implement it.

Comment: It is not the answer what I waiting for, if you can read the post again and give me an answer for all the parts of the question, I will be thanks.

Comment: @MohammedFayyad — I've read it again, and it does answer it (although you will need to read the part of the spec about implementations to get an answer for the second part of it).